# Fundamental solution of parabolic PDE with variable coefficients

Tags: parabolic-pde, heat-equation, green-function

Let us consider the parabolic operator
$$
\mathcal{L} = \partial_t - \nabla_x \cdot(a(x)\nabla_x)
$$
over a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$. The coefficient matrix $a(x)$ is elliptic and bounded, so that the problem $\mathcal{L}u=f$ is well posed (given some boundary and initial conditions). Moreover, the coefficient matrix is real and symmetric.

The **fundamental solution** of the operator $\mathcal{L}$ is defined as solution $Z(x,t,y,s)$ of
\begin{align}
\partial_t Z(x,t,y,s) - \nabla_x \cdot(a(x)\nabla_x Z(x,t,y,s) ) &= \delta(x-y)\delta(t-s) \quad (x,t)\in\Omega \times (0,T)\\
Z(x,t,y,s) &= 0 \quad (x,t)\in\partial\Omega \times (0,T)\\
Z(x,s,y,s) &= 0 \quad x\in\Omega,
\end{align}

where $y\in\Omega$ and $s<t$.

What can one say about the derivatives of $Z$ with respect to the variables $y$ and $s$? Can one conclude that 
\begin{equation}
\partial_s Z(x,t,y,s) + \nabla_y \cdot(a(y)\nabla_y Z(x,t,y,s) ) = \delta(x-y)\delta(t-s)
\end{equation}
or a similar result?

**NOTE**: the last equation is true for the fundamental solution of the heat equation (constant coefficient) in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is there a way to conclude the same result for variable coefficients on a bounded domain?